# Swift tableview could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array named Beacon Array, it stores beacon information, the array type is AnyObject. I have an another array which stores some names like this.

The numbers should match the beacon minor I saved in the first array. So that in my table view I can display the name in the list by distance order.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation




class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,     UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var refresh: UIBarButtonItem!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")!, identifier: "Beacon1")
let name = [
    513: "Max",
    65505: "Juan",
    512: "Jack"
]


var size = 0

var beaconArray = []

var timer = NSTimer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    //self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: ("testing"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.name.count
    //return self.beaconArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    if self.beaconArray.count > 0 {
        let minor = self.beaconArray[indexPath.row].minor
        println(minor)
    }


    //cell.textLabel?.text = "\(minor)"//self.name[self.beaconArray[indexPath.row].minor] //[indexPath.row]
    //cell.textLabel?.text = self.name[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

 /* func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}*/

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    //print(beacons)

    self.beaconArray = [AnyObject](beacons)


   // self.beaconArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator()

  /*  for beacon in beaconArray {
   println("ID: \(beacon.minor) Accuracy: \(beacon.accuracy), RSSI: \(beacon.rssi)")

    }
    println("-------RESULT END---------------")

    self.size = beaconArray.count
   */

    //println("Size: \(self.size)")


   }

}
```

Comment: `name` is not an array its dictionary. Can you please post `becaonArray` as well

Comment: I added in the quesion

Comment: I find tableview show immediately after compile, but beacons takes minutes to find. after find beacons, i need call the table view again

Comment: And whats your return value of numberOfRowsInSection ? Can you post it as well ?

Comment: I post everything on it now

Answer (score 0):

Okay now I see a lot of fixes that need to be done in your code. First of all `beaconArray` type should be declared as array of CLBeacon

```
var beaconArray : [CLBeacon] = []
```

Secondly on numberOfRowsInSection return `beaconArray` count. This way you will get sure that list will be populated only after getting beacons

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.beaconArray.count
}
```

And finally after getting beacons put them in `beaconArray` and reload your table view data

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    //print(beacons)

    self.beaconArray = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i really appreciate. it works now

Comment: @GuanNanYao Glad to hear that, mark this answer as accepted please so other can get rid of it